# How to Move TempDB Files to a Different Drive or Folder?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tempdb, datafile

How do I move my **TempDB Data or Log File(s)** from wherever they are now **to a different Drive or Folder**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moving the TempDB files is a 2-step process:

1. Tell SQL **where** you want your new TempDB files to go to
2. **Restart** the `SQL Server` service for the change to take effect

To tell SQL where to create the new TempDB files, you can use:

```
DECLARE @newDriveAndFolder VARCHAR(8000);

SET @newDriveAndFolder = 'Z:\YourTempDBfolder';

SELECT [name] AS [Logical Name]
    ,physical_name AS [Current Location]
    ,state_desc AS [Status]
    ,size / 128 AS [Size(MB)] --Number of 8KB pages / 128 = MB
    ,'ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(f.[name])
    + CHAR(9) /* Tab */
    + ',FILENAME = ''' + @newDriveAndFolder + CHAR(92) /* Backslash */ + f.[name]
    + CASE WHEN f.[type] = 1 /* Log */ THEN '.ldf' ELSE '.mdf' END  + ''''
    + ');'
    AS [Create new TempDB files]
FROM sys.master_files f
WHERE f.database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb')
ORDER BY f.[type];
```

This will generate the T-SQL statements you need to run to move the files to the new `drive:\folder` you want. (click image to make larger)

[image: Image showing 2 rows with details on TempDB files and T-SQL statements to move them]

When you have ran your moving statements, you can run the above query again, to check that the `Current Location` column is now showing your new `drive:\folder`.

[image: Image showing TempDB files' new locations]

Once you're happy with your changes, **restart the SQL Server service**.

Comment: Good idea! Good place to post this.

Comment: Cheers Brent! Kudos for the idea goes to your blog post :-) https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/11/move-tempdb-another-drive-folder/

Answer (score 6):

The calculation of the size(MB) in the script above is off. Don't forget that size in sys.master_files is the number of 8KB pages. Here is the correct script:

```
DECLARE @newDriveAndFolder VARCHAR(8000);

SET @newDriveAndFolder = 'Z:\YourTempDBfolder';

SELECT [name] AS [Logical Name]
    ,physical_name AS [Current Location]
    ,state_desc AS [Status]
    ,size*8/1024 AS [Size(MB)] --Number of 8KB pages dived by 1024
    ,'ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(f.[name])
    + CHAR(9) /* Tab */
    + ',FILENAME = ''' + @newDriveAndFolder + CHAR(92) /* Backslash */ + f.[name]
    + CASE WHEN f.[type] = 1 /* Log */ THEN '.ldf' ELSE '.mdf' END  + ''''
    + ');'
    AS [Create new TempDB files]
FROM sys.master_files f
WHERE f.database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb')
ORDER BY f.[type];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out! I usually remember the 8K page thing, but I must have not had my morning tea that day... ^_^